# How do I choose where to place my add-in button in OWA?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I made my first Outlook web add-in and I was wondering how I could place the button right here automatically without going into the OWA settings by hand. Is there a way a place it here via the manifest? I tried looking up online the manifest syntax but I could not find how to do it on the official DOCS.

[Here's what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVdb6.png)

Comment: This is out of scope for a developer. But users can install the add-in and the add-in can be pinned to the email items for easy access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is out of scope for a developer. But users can install the add-in and the add-in can be pinned to the email items for easy access.